# Material Ui Table Sort with pagination

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get my table to sort via the different columns following the material UI documentation. I'm not sure why its not working but upon clicking on the header the sort order shows up and i can see everything firing it just not sorting. I believe i have a tiny error somewhere in my code and after staring at it for hours i cant seem to find it.

[Material UI Table Documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/)

Working CodeSandbox I'm trying to follow as well that matches the documentation: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/table-sort-7tg1j?file=/demo.js:4603-4690)

Code base:

```
function TablePaginationActions(props) {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const { count, page, rowsPerPage, onChangePage } = props;

    const handleFirstPageButtonClick = (event) => {
        onChangePage(event, 0);
    };

    const handleBackButtonClick = (event) => {
        onChangePage(event, page - 1);
    };

    const handleNextButtonClick = (event) => {
        onChangePage(event, page + 1);
    };

    const handleLastPageButtonClick = (event) => {
        onChangePage(event, Math.max(0, Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1));
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ flexShrink: 0 }}>
            <IconButton
                onClick={handleFirstPageButtonClick}
                disabled={page === 0}
                aria-label="first page"
            >
                {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <LastPageIcon /> : <FirstPageIcon />}
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton onClick={handleBackButtonClick} disabled={page === 0} aria-label="previous page">
                {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowRight /> : <KeyboardArrowLeft />}
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
                onClick={handleNextButtonClick}
                disabled={page >= Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1}
                aria-label="next page"
            >
                {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowLeft /> : <KeyboardArrowRight />}
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
                onClick={handleLastPageButtonClick}
                disabled={page >= Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1}
                aria-label="last page"
            >
                {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <FirstPageIcon /> : <LastPageIcon />}
            </IconButton>
        </div>
    );
}

TablePaginationActions.propTypes = {
    count: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    onChangePage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    page: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    rowsPerPage: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
  return order === "desc"
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}

function stableSort(array, comparator) {
  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) return order;
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map(el => el[0]);
}

const headCells = [
  {
    id: "",
    numeric: false,
    disablePadding: true,
    label: ""
  },
  { id: "Holiday", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Holiday" },
  { id: "Date", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Date" },
  { id: "Branch", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Branch" },
  { id: "Hours", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Hours" },
  { id: "Web", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Web" },
  { id: "Phone", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Phone" },
  { id: "CoOp", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "CoOp" },
  { id: "Submitted", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Submitted" },
  { id: "SubmittedBy", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "SubmittedBy" },
  { id: "Published", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Published" },
  { id: "PublishedBy", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "PublishedBy" },
];

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  visuallyHidden: {
    border: 0,
    clip: "rect(0 0 0 0)",
    height: 1,
    margin: -1,
    overflow: "hidden",
    padding: 0,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 20,
    width: 1
  }
}));

function EnhancedTableHead(props) {
  const {
    classes,
    order,
    orderBy,
    onRequestSort
  } = props;
  const createSortHandler = property => event => {
    onRequestSort(event, property);
  };

  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        {headCells.map(headCell => (
          <TableCell
            key={headCell.id}
            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
          >
            <TableSortLabel
              active={orderBy === headCell.id}
              direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
              onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
            >
              {headCell.label}
              {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                <span className={classes.visuallyHidden}>
                  {order === "desc" ? "sorted descending" : "sorted ascending"}
                </span>
              ) : null}
            </TableSortLabel>
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
}

const HolidaySettings = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);
    const anchorRef = React.useRef(null);
    const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [dialogData, setDialogData] = React.useState({});
    const [showInactive, setShowInactive] = useState(false);
    const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
    const [order, setOrder] = React.useState("asc");
    const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState("Holiday");

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onInit = useCallback(() => {
        dispatch(actions.holiday_getHolidays());
        dispatch(actions.holiday_getProductionHolidays());
    }, [dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (loading) {
            onInit();
        }
    }, [loading]);

    const rows = useSelector(state => {
        let results = [];

        if (showInactive) {
            results = state.holidays.holidays;
        } else {            
            results = state.holidays.activeHolidays;
        }

        if (state.holidays.holidays && loading) {
            setLoading(false);
            setSearchResults(results);
        }

        return results;
    });

    const handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
        const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
        setOrder(isAsc ? "desc" : "asc");
        setOrderBy(property);
    };

    const handleToggle = () => {
        setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen);
    };

    const handleDialogOpen = (dataElement) => {
        setDialogData(dataElement);
        setDialogOpen(true);
        setOpen(false);
    }

    const handleHolidayDelete = (dataElement) => {
        dispatch(actions.holiday_deleteHoliday(dataElement));
    }

    const handleDialogClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
        setDialogOpen(false);
    };

    const handleClose = (event) => {
        if (anchorRef.current && anchorRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
            return;
        }

        setOpen(false);
    };

    const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
        setPage(newPage);
    };

    const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
        setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
        setPage(0);
    };

    const handleInactiveChange = (e) => {
        e.persist();
        const { checked } = e.target;
        setShowInactive(checked)
    }

    const handleSearch = (e) => {
        e.persist();
        const searchValue = e.target.value;
        let results = _.map(rows, function(holiday) {
            if (holiday.HolidayName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1) return holiday;
        });
        results = _.without(results, undefined);
        setSearchResults(results);
    }



    return (
        <div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                    <div className="card-chart card">
                        <div className="card-header">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-sm-12 d-flex">
                                    <h4 className="card-title">Holiday Settings</h4>

                                    <div
                                        className="ml-auto mr-5"
                                        ref={anchorRef}
                                        aria-controls={open ? 'menu-list-grow' : undefined}
                                        aria-haspopup="true"
                                        onClick={handleToggle}>
                                        <SettingsOutlinedIcon style={{ fontSize: 20 }} />
                                        {open ? (
                                            <ExpandLess style={{ fontSize: 12 }} />
                                        ) : (
                                                <ExpandMore style={{ fontSize: 12 }} />
                                            )}
                                    </div>
                                    <Popper open={open} anchorEl={anchorRef.current} role={undefined} transition disablePortal>
                                        {({ TransitionProps, placement }) => (
                                            <Grow
                                                {...TransitionProps}
                                                style={{ transformOrigin: placement === 'bottom' ? 'center top' : 'center bottom' }}
                                            >
                                                <Paper>
                                                    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
                                                        <MenuList autoFocusItem={open} id="menu-list-grow">
                                                            <MenuItem onClick={handleDialogOpen}>Add Holiday</MenuItem>
                                                            <MenuItem>
                                                                <FormControlLabel className=""
                                                                    label="Show Inactive"
                                                                    control={
                                                                        <Checkbox
                                                                            checked={showInactive || false}
                                                                            value={showInactive}
                                                                            onChange={handleInactiveChange}
                                                                            name="Show Inactive"
                                                                            color="primary"
                                                                        />
                                                                    }
                                                                />
                                                            </MenuItem>
                                                        </MenuList>
                                                    </ClickAwayListener>
                                                </Paper>
                                            </Grow>
                                        )}
                                    </Popper>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {loading ? (
                            <CanvasLoader loading={loading} />
                        ) : (
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <div className="text-left col-12">
                                        <Paper>
                                            <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Search" onChange={handleSearch}/>
                                            <TableContainer component={Paper} className="holidaysTableContainer">
                                                <Table className="w-100" aria-label="simple table">
                                                    <EnhancedTableHead
                                                      classes={classes}
                                                      order={order}
                                                      orderBy={orderBy}
                                                      onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
                                                      rowCount={rows.length}
                                                    />
                                                    <TableBody>
                                                        {stableSort(searchResults, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                                                            .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                                                            .map((row, index) => {
                                                                return (
                                                                    <TableRow key={row.RowId} id={row.Id} className={row.Active ? '' : 'inactive-row'}>
                                                                        <TableCell>{<div className="d-flex flex-align-center justify-content-center"><CreateOutlinedIcon className="holidayEditIcon" style={{ color: '#00f2c3' }} onClick={() => { handleDialogOpen(row); }} /> {row.Active ? (<DeleteForeverOutlinedIcon className="holidayDeleteIcon" style={{ color: '#fd5d93' }} onClick={() => { handleHolidayDelete(row); }} />) : (<div></div>)}</div>}</TableCell>
                                                                        <TableCell>{row.HolidayName}</TableCell>
                                                                        <TableCell>{moment(row.HolidayDate).format('ddd, MMM Do YYYY')}</TableCell>
                                                                        <TableCell>{row.Branch ? row.Branch : 'All'}</TableCell>
                                                                        <TableCell>{row.Hours ? row.Hours : 'Closed'}</TableCell>
                                                                        <TableCell>{(row.Web ? <DoneIcon style={{ color: '#00f2c3' }} value="true" /> : <CloseIcon style={{ color: '#fd5d93' }} value="false" />)}</TableCell>
                                                                        <TableCell>{(row.Phone ? <DoneIcon style={{ color: '#00f2c3' }} value="true" /> : <CloseIcon style={{ color: '#fd5d93' }} value="false" />)}</TableCell>
                                                                        <TableCell>{(row.CoOp ? <DoneIcon style={{ color: '#00f2c3' }} value="true" /> : <CloseIcon style={{ color: '#fd5d93' }} value="false" />)}</TableCell>
                                                                        <TableCell>{(row.Submitted ? moment(row.Submitted).format('MMM Do, YYYY') : false)}</TableCell>
                                                                        <TableCell>{row.SubmittedBy}</TableCell>
                                                                        <TableCell>{(row.Published ? moment(row.Published).format('MMM Do, YYYY') : false)}</TableCell>
                                                                        <TableCell>{row.PublishedBy}</TableCell>
                                                                    </TableRow>
                                                                )
                                                        })}
                                                    </TableBody>
                                                    <TableFooter>
                                                        <TableRow>
                                                            <TablePagination
                                                                rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, { label: 'All', value: -1 }]}
                                                                colSpan={12}
                                                                count={searchResults.length}
                                                                rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                                                                page={page}
                                                                onChangePage={handleChangePage}
                                                                onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                                                                ActionsComponent={TablePaginationActions}
                                                            />
                                                        </TableRow>
                                                    </TableFooter>
                                                </Table>
                                            </TableContainer>
                                        </Paper>
                                        <HolidayDialog open={dialogOpen} onClose={handleDialogClose} data={dialogData} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )} 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HolidaySettings;
```

Comment: If you're sorting paginated data, you probably need to run the sort on the backend. Otherwise, when the user goes to the next page, they will get a set of data that doesn't come after the previous set.

Comment: @CharlesBamford the material UI table handles just that: https://material-ui.com/components/tables/

Comment: can you check if `orderBy` value is same as `id` of head cell and `handleRequestSort` function getting correct `property`.

Comment: @HarishSharma yes i can confirm within `createSortHandler` the `property` value is `headCell.id` which for Holiday header equal `Holiday` and then inside `handleRequestSort` the `orderBy` value is `Holiday`

Comment: @HarishSharma I can also confirm that `handleRequestSort` is getting the correct `property`

Comment: Can you console.log inside `useSelector`. May be it is resetting `searchResult`

Comment: @HarishSharma your right! every time i try to sort its getting inside the `useSelector` how do i prevent this??

Comment: I haven't used `useSelector` but I as far as I know You should avoid setting state in `useSelector` because `useSelector` re-rendered each time any part of the redux store change.

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: @HarishSharma i believe your on the right track but i dont know how to correct the issue

Comment: @CharlesL. In `TableCell` you're mentioning `HolidayName` key but in `HeadCell` id is `Holiday`. Can you try making these two keys same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your code, `TableHead` and `TableBody` are rendered with different ids.

- **Holiday name** in `TableHead` has `id = 'Holiday'` but in `TableBody`, it is `'HolidayName'`.
- **Holiday Date** in `TableHead` has `id = 'Date'` but in `TableBody`, it is `'HolidayDate'`.

> You have to assign a similar string as `id` to `TableHead` and `TableBody`.

So try below changes to make sorting work

```
const headCells = [
  {
    id: "",
    numeric: false,
    disablePadding: true,
    label: ""
  },
  { id: "HolidayName", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Holiday" },
  { id: "HolidayDate", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Date" },
  { id: "Branch", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Branch" },
  { id: "Hours", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Hours" },
  { id: "Web", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Web" },
  { id: "Phone", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Phone" },
  { id: "CoOp", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "CoOp" },
  { id: "Submitted", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Submitted" },
  { id: "SubmittedBy", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "SubmittedBy" },
  { id: "Published", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Published" },
  { id: "PublishedBy", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "PublishedBy" },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be useful to someone...I had the same problem but didn't want to follow the MUI documentation because their solution is too complicated. This may not be the best solution, but it is far simpler:

```
import { FunctionComponent, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { fetchForms } from 'api';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { URLParams, AssignedForm } from 'types';
import {
  Box,
  Paper,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TablePagination,
  TableRow,
  TableSortLabel,
} from '@mui/material';

export type OrderType = {
  order: 'asc' | 'desc';
  orderBy: string;
};

const tableColumns = [
  { key: 'id', label: 'Id' },
  { key: 'title', label: 'Title' },
  { key: 'createdDateTime', label: 'Date assigned' },
  { key: 'submittedAt', label: 'Date submitted' },
  { key: 'status', label: 'Status' },
  { key: 'actions', label: 'Actions' },
];

export const Forms: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const params: URLParams = useParams();
  const id = params.id ?? '';
  const [assignedForms, setAssignedForms] = useState<AssignedForm[] | null>(null);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [orderData, setOrderData] = useState<OrderType>({ order: 'desc', orderBy: 'createdDateTime' });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const formAnswers = await fetchForms(id, {
        page: page,
        pageSize: 10,
        orderParams: { order: orderData.order, orderBy: orderData.orderBy },
      });
      if (formAnswers) {
        setAssignedForms(formAnswers.data);
        setTotal(formAnswers.meta.pagination.total);
      }
    };
    void getData();
  }, [id, page, orderData]);

  const handleChangePage = (newPage: number) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const changeTableSort = (key: string) => {
    setOrderData({
      order: orderData.order === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc',
      orderBy: key,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Box>
        <TableContainer component={Paper} sx={{ marginTop: '0.5rem' }}>
          <Table sx={{ minWidth: 300 }} size="small" aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                {tableColumns.map((item) => {
                  return (
                    <TableCell
                      key={item.key}
                      id={item.key}
                      sortDirection={orderData.orderBy === item.key ? orderData.order : false}
                    >
                      <TableSortLabel
                        active={orderData.orderBy === item.key}
                        direction={orderData.orderBy === item.key ? orderData.order : 'asc'}
                        onClick={() => changeTableSort(item.key)}
                      >
                        {item.label}
                      </TableSortLabel>
                    </TableCell>
                  );
                })}
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>{/* {... TABLE BODY ...} */}</TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        {assignedForms && assignedForms.length > 0 && (
          <TablePagination
            rowsPerPageOptions={[]}
            component="div"
            count={total}
            rowsPerPage={10}
            page={page}
            onPageChange={(_: unknown, page: number) => handleChangePage(page)}
          />
        )}
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```